# stop dragging in slick carousel

Tags: jquery

I am working on a small project where i am using slick carousel. The problem is I want to stop dragging in case of first and last element. Any idea how to do this?

how to stop dragging in case of first and last element ?

```
var readyToDrag = true;
        jQuery('.responsive').slick({
            dots: false,
            infinite: false,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            draggable: true,
            onBeforeChange: function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
                if(event.currentSlide == 3){
                    readyToDrag = false;
                    alert(readyToDrag);
                }
            },

            draggable: readyToDrag,
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 1000,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2,
                    infinite: false,
                    dots: false
                }
            }, {
                breakpoint: 999,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2,
                    infinite: false
                }
            }, {
                breakpoint: 767,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2,
                    infinite: false,

                    draggable: readyToDrag,

                }
            }]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I am late to the party ;P
Here's my solution for future visitors, check it out on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boka8yrj/1/).

### How it works?

**Some observations**

1. Slick's drag work by changing (and animating) the `transform` css property
2. The property value must always be `0 <= value <= ($containerWidth - $trackwidth)` where *$containerWidth* is the width of the element containing the *visible slides* and *$trackWidth* is the width of the element containing all the slides.
3. If the value is `> 0` then there is a left-overscroll and if it is `>
   ($containerWidth - $trackwidth)` then there is right-overscroll
4. The change in value is assigned as the value for `x-axis` in `translate3d()` transformation.

**Stopping the transformation from happening:**
The key to this solution is intercepting and preventing (if necessary) the transformation to be applied to the *slick element*.
To do this, what I did was

1. Patch jQuery's `css()` method to intercept calls and check for `transform` css property
2. If found then trigger a custom event and delegate transform call to it. The handler will decide whether or not to allow the transformation.
3. Inside the handler simply check for this condition
   `0 <= value <= ($containerWidth - $trackwidth)` to be true and allow the transformation.

**The interceptor:**

```
(function($) {
    // use regex to extract x-translation value
  var reg = /-?\d+/g;

  $.fn.css = (function(orig) {
    return function CSSTranslateListener() {
      var isTranslate = !!arguments[0]['transform']
      if (!isTranslate) {
        // apply regular changes
        orig.apply(this, arguments);
      } else {
        // is a translate event!
        // trigger an event with a pseudo-resolve that we can call
        // if we want the translation to happen and a the tranlation value
        // debugger;
        var evt = new $.Event("slickEdgeTrigger");
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        var resolver = orig.bind.apply(orig, [].concat([this], args))
        $(this).trigger(evt, [resolver, +args[0]['transform'].match(reg)[1]])
      }
    }
  })($.fn.css)
})(jQuery)
```

**The Handler:**

```
// $w is the width of container (see https://jsfiddle.net/boka8yrj)
$('.carousel').on('slickEdgeTrigger', function(evt, fn, by) {
    if(by >= ($w - $('.slick-track').width()) && by <= 0){
        fn()
    }
  })
});
```

**Caveats:**

1. Will intercept all transform calls and not only Slick's call
2. Performance can be an issue on bigger slides or pages with too many calls to `$(...).css()`

**Is there any other way?**
Well, [Slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/) is an Open-source project so you can always download a copy and modify it to match your needs.To achieve the above behavior, you can add the interception and handler logic at [this point](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/1.6.0/slick/slick.js#L1893). This is where the values for transformation are calculated, so you just simply need to check for the condition that I mentioned above inside [this](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/1.6.0/slick/slick.js#L1893) function and return early if the condition is false.